# Initializing 'TBParsing *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

Tags: xcode

Initializing 'TBParsing *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

My code:

```
TBParsing *parsing = [[TBParsing alloc]initWithUrlString:@"http://xx.com/info.xml"];
```

How should I fix this?

check the code here https://github.com/rkumawat/TBXMLParsing-Library

Comment: What is TBParsing? That's not an Apple-provided class, so explain where it comes from. There's nothing obviously wrong with your line of code, otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Change:</strike>

```
-(void)initWithUrlString:(NSString *)URLString;
```

to:

```
-(id)initWithUrlString:(NSString *)URLString;
```

In `TBParsing.{h,m}`.

The `initWithUrlString` method is not an Objective-C *init* method in the traditional sense.  You need to use the like this:

```
TBParsing *parsing = [[TBParsing alloc] init];
[parsing initWithUrlString:@"http://xx.com/info.xml"];
```

However that method needs to be re-written so it can be used in the manner you show in your code fragment.